# What are these New York area buildings?

Tags: 20th-century, new-york-state, photo-identification

I've got two photos of buildings taken around June 1958.  They are labeled as being Tarrytown, New York, but I wasn't able to find the building they go to.  If not Tarrytown, I would expect them to be within the general vicinity along the Hudson River.

Here is first one:

[image]

And next photo on the same roll of film is this one:

[image]

Can anyone identify either or both?

Comment: Isn't the first one [Grant's tomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant%27s_Tomb)?

Comment: Yes, that looks like a match, so is the other building one nearby?

Comment: I wondered if it might be [Riverside Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverside_Church), but I'm not familiar enough with NY to be sure.

Comment: Here is photo that appears to show both buildings: http://nyc-architecture.com/HAR/HAR008-Grant1.jpg

Comment: @sempaiscuba Yes, Riverside page says across the street, plus see photo I pasted above.  I'd say you have an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first building is the ***General Grant National Memorial***, perhaps better known as [Grant's Tomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grant%27s_Tomb). As the Wikipedia article notes:

> It is a classical domed mausoleum, located in the Morningside Heights neighborhood of Upper Manhattan in New York City. The structure is located in the median of Riverside Drive at 122nd Street, across from Riverside Church to the southeast and Riverside Park to the west.

---

That last comment was a pointer to the identity of the building in your second picture, which looks to be [Riverside Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverside_Church).  The fact that this church is across 122nd Street from Grant's Tomb explains why it was the next photograph on the roll.